# Yocto 2.4.2 failed to do_package_qa task

Tags: yocto

I am working with Yocto project version Rocko 2.4.2, Linux LTS4.4, cortexA15 ARM arch
When I bitbake weston package (v2.0), the error generated

```
ERROR: weston-2.0.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libweston-2/gl-renderer.so contained in package libweston-2 requires libGLESv2.so, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libweston-2? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: weston-2.0.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/bin/weston-simple-egl contained in package weston-examples requires libGLESv2.so, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_weston-examples? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: weston-2.0.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: weston-2.0.0-r0 do_package_qa: Function failed: do_package_qa
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/server-build/RZG_YoctoProject/build/tmp/work/cortexa15hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/weston/2.0.0-r0/temp/log.do_package_qa.8133
ERROR: Task (/home/server-build/RZG_YoctoProject/build/../poky/meta/recipes-graphics/wayland/weston_2.0.0.bb:do_package_qa) failed with exit code '1'
```

I tried to set "RDEPENDS_weston-examples = "libGLESv2" but it's still failed.

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'libGLESv2' (but /home/server-build/RZG_YoctoProject/build/../poky/meta/recipes-graphics/wayland/weston_2.0.0.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'libGLESv2' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['libGLESv2']
ERROR: Required build target 'weston' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['weston', 'libGLESv2']
```

This error happened due to new structure and syntax of Yocto 2.4.2.
Anyone who is running into the same issue ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show your `conf/local.conf`

Comment: Should use "libgles2" instead or skip QA task **do_package_qa[noexec] = "1"**

Answer (score 0):

`libGLESv2.so` belongs to `libgl-mesa` package. You should use this package instead of 'libGLESv2'. The name of the library is not always the same as the package name.

#### Option 1

You should add the package to DEPENDS if it is a library required for compile or RDEPENDS if is a library required just on run-time.

If you have multiple sub-packages on a recipe, it might be wise to specify what are the DEPENDS/RDEPENDS for each sub-package, but if you have a single package or all your packages DEPENDS/RDEPENDS on the same package, you can simplify the recipe by making all sub-packages use the same package.

Example of how to make a package be required by all the sub-packages:

```
DEPENDS += "libgl-mesa"
```

Example of how to make a package be required for specific sub-packages:

```
DEPENDS_${PN}-mysubpackage += "libgl-mesa"
DEPENDS_libweston-2 += "libgl-mesa"
DEPENDS_weston-examples += "libgl-mesa"
```

Note: PN means package name;

#### Option 2

Other option, no so recommended, could be disable the file-rdeps validation.
Disable validation for all sub-packages:

```
INSANE_SKIP = "file-rdeps"
```

Disable validation for specific sub-packages:

```
INSANE_SKIP_${PN}-mysubpackage = "file-rdeps"
INSANE_SKIP_libweston-2 = "file-rdeps"
INSANE_SKIP_weston-examples = "file-rdeps"
```

#### Extra:

Note that, in newer yocto versions, such as Kirkstone, the syntax for **sub-packages** changed to:

```
DEPENDS:${PN}-mysubpackage += "libgl-mesa"
DEPENDS:libweston-2 += "libgl-mesa"
DEPENDS:weston-examples += "libgl-mesa"
```

and

```
INSANE_SKIP:${PN}-mysubpackage = "file-rdeps"
INSANE_SKIP:libweston-2 = "file-rdeps"
INSANE_SKIP:weston-examples = "file-rdeps"
```